# angular reactive form test not working when setting value. How to unit test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to unit test a simple reactive form in Angular 5, and don't understand why setting the value in a unit test does not work.

I build the form in my ngOnInit, with the formbuilder:

### component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
    email: ['', [Validators.required, ValidateEmail]],
    password: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}
```

In my unit test, I have the normal CLI setutp, in befofreEach:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignInComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

My **unit test** then looks like this:

```
fit('login-form printing unexpected value', fakeAsync(() => {
  const form = component.loginForm;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

  form.controls['email'].setValue('aaa');
  console.log(form.get('email')); // PRINTS bbb

  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

  form.controls['email'].setValue('bbb');
  console.log(form.get('email'));// PRINTS bbb

}));
```

I tried printing only

```
console.log(form.get('email').value)
```

And then the value is aaa and bbb as expected.
I am very confused and hope you can help me understand this.

Comment: Can you explain your problem in details here? I can see that you are able to print the values after setting them up in your test.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a function defined in the test suite to update the form values:

```
function updateForm(name: string, id: string, comments: string) {
    component.myForm.controls['name'].setValue(name);
    component.myForm.controls['id'].setValue(id);
    component.myForm.controls['comments'].setValue(comments);
}
```

and you can call this function to set values from your test case:

```
it('form value should update from form changes', fakeAsync(() => {
    updateForm('Martin K', 'xyzi', 'Test');
    expect(component.myForm.value).toEqual(page.validFormValues); // validate against another value.
    expect(component.myForm.invalid).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

Hope this helps.